# how to get the id of the previously selected element in jquery

Tags: jquery

i am stuck in one logic

i have to get the value of the previous li a element which had class active! and i am unsuccessful till now,
here is one example

```
<ul>
  <li class='active'><a href='' value='1'>One</a></li>
  <li><a href='' value='2'>Two</a></li>
  <li><a href='' value='3'>Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

By default one is active,
but when i click three, i want to grab the value of one i.e i want to get attr of a (1),and three becomes the active li,
when i click two, i've to grab the value of three, and two becomes active.

i am seriously doomed ! any help would be really appreciated. The code i've tried is pure rubbish . Please save me !! :' (

Comment: value attributes in a tag?!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
     var prev_act_id = $('li.active a').attr('value');
     $('ul li').removeClass('active');
     $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
     alert('Previous value is ' + prev_act_id);
});
```

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Qbj3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
var previous;
$('li').click(function() {
    previous = $(this).parent().children('.active').index() + 1;
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just paste the code:

```
var $active = $(".active");
$("li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        return;
    }
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $active.removeClass("active");
    $active = $(this);
});
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/VLXsz/1/

hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Save previous item in a variable:

```
var previous = null;

$('a').click(function(){
    previous.parent().removeClass('active');
    previous = $(this);
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
})
```

Than if you want to get previous value:

```
if(previous !== null) {
    previous_value = previous.val();
} else {
    previous_value = null;
}
```